# Creating a dynamic Perl function which uses a variable's value at time of function declaration

Tags: perl

I'd like to create a dynamic function that uses (evaluates?) the value of a variable at the time the function is declared.

The example below requires $var to exist as a global variable so it can be used when the function is invoked:

```
my $var = 'something';

someFunction(sub { return $_[0] eq $var; });
```

but I'm guessing there is some way to create the dynamic function so it is declared like this:

```
someFunction(sub { return $_[0] eq 'something'; });
```

How can I do that!? :)

Comment: What you're looking for is called a closure, but I'm not clear on exactly what you're trying to do.  Are you calling `someFunction` and passing it a closure you've created, or are you trying to write a `someFunction` that creates and returns a closure?

Comment: The former. A closure seems overkill though. At the time the function is created there's nothing "variable" about $var - it's effectively a constant.

Comment: I think I want this:
someFunction(eval "return sub { \$_[0] eq '$var'; }");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little sloppy, but it works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl                                                             

use warnings;
use strict;

my $var = 'something';

my $f1 = sub { my $v = $_[0]; return sub { return $_[0] eq  $v } };

my $f2 = $f1->($var);

$var = 'other thing';

print $f2->('something');
```

With lambda, all things are possible.

Comment: It's not simply lambda functions (what another language calls anonymous functions) that make it possible, it's closures.

Comment: @ikegami - All real languages with lambdas use them to create closures :-)

Comment: Yes, I know, I've written Scheme compilers before Perl existed.  Hence my reference to "real languages"; i.e., those in which anonymous functions can be used to create closures.  Alonzo Church showed long ago that lambda is all you need, provided it's a real lambda, and not some poor substitute.

Comment: Ever hear of the "lambda calculus"?  I suppose you would call it the "closure calculus", but my term predates yours by a few decades and I am a bit of a traditionalist

Comment: But in my code above, `$f1` and `$f2` are pure functions, just like you would write in the untyped lambda calculus.  In Scheme, `f1` would be `(lambda (x) (lambda (y) (equal? x y))`; the lambda calculus equivalent is not much more complicated.  `f2` is just `f1` applied to the string "something".  This has nothing to do with closures per se and everything to do with lambda in the original "lambda calculus" sense.  (The original questioner's code is a better illustration of closures/variable capture in a not-very-lambda-calculus sense.)

Answer (score 1):

How about capturing a local copy of it?

```
someFunction( do { my $v = $var; sub { $_[0] eq $v } } );
```

That way, even if `$var` is later modified, the anonymous sub is still using its local copy of it from with the original value.

Comment: I suspected I would need to do something icky with `eval`, but this is cleaner (at the slight inconvenience of not being able to see the value if you Data::Dumper such things).

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with an old, simple, straight closure?

```
sub genf { my $v = shift; sub { shift eq $v } }

my $f = genf('something'); # Or genf($var)

print &$f('something');
print &$f('another thing');
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the others, I think that a closure is fine for this purpose. I wouldn't even be surprised if the compiler can optimize it down to what you expect, though I don't have the guru-ness to prove it.

Still, I can attempt what you asked, though I don't recommend it.

```
my $var = 'something';

my $sub = eval 'sub { return $_[0] eq \'' . $var .  '\'}';

someFunction( $sub );
```

You build up the code reference as strings, using the value of `$var` and then when you `eval` it, it is compiled to Perl code. Notice that you have to include extra quotes since by the time the code is evaluated, the contents of `$var` will be a bare string.

Again though, this isn't recommended. Why? Because its dangerous, especially if the content of `$var` comes from the outside world.